# Wordpress ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

On top of http://www.puhy.cz (ZenCart) I have some links (green header "Recenze Služby Projekty" to blog on worpress on subdomain ( http://www.firma.puhy.cz )

```
http://firma.puhy.cz/projekty

http://firma.puhy.cz/recenze

http://firma.puhy.cz/sluzby
```

Sometimes after click to this links it ends:

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

The .htaccess file on wordpress:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Please help me with this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any more .htaccess files?

Comment: No, in .htaccess is only this: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Comment: In that case look into your `WP permalink settings`.

Comment: Many thanks. I have problem with permissions on .htaccess file. Now I think it's ok. Please can you test it?

Comment: Yes tested, looks good now.

Answer (score 0):

What definitely helped for me was changing the site_url and home_url in the wp_options table: If you haven't any www in your url, add it. Otherwise remove the www in front of your url.